# ksh-style left and right string stripping up to matched expression?

Tags: python, regex, string, ksh

How can one strip the left parts and right parts off strings up to a matching expression as in ksh?

For instance:

```
${name##*/}

${name%/*}
```

(see http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html for ksh examples).

I can't seem to figure out a simple way of doing this using re module or string module but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ksh:

```
$ s='abc/def/ghi'
$ echo ${s%%/*}
abc
$ echo ${s%/*}
abc/def
$ echo ${s#*/}
def/ghi
$ echo ${s##*/}
ghi
```

Python:

```
>>> s='abc/def/ghi'
>>> print s[:s.find("/")]
abc
>>> print s[:s.rfind("/")]
abc/def
>>> print s[s.find("/")+1:]
def/ghi
>>> print s[s.rfind("/")+1:]
ghi
```

**Edit:**

To handle the case in which the pattern is missing, as pointed out by **ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ**:

```
>>> s='abc/def/ghi'
>>> t='no slash here'
>>> print s[:s.find("/") % (len(s) + 1)]
abc
>>> print t[:t.find("/") % (len(t) + 1)]
no slash here
>>> print s[:s.rfind("/") % (len(s) + 1)]
abc/def
>>> print t[:t.rfind("/") % (len(t) + 1)]
no slash here
>>> print s[s.find("/")+1:]
def/ghi
>>> print t[t.find("/")+1:]
no slash here
>>> print s[s.rfind("/")+1:]
ghi
>>> print t[t.rfind("/")+1:]
no slash here
```

Comment: The r?find solutions are flawed in the case where the input string doesn't have the pattern; in this case, the "/" character. `s="no slash here"; print s[:s.find("/")], s[:s.rfind("/")]`. If you fix this, I'll happily remove my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
${name##*/}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
re.match(".*?([^/]*)$")[1]
```

---

```
${name%/*}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
re.match("(.*?)[^/]*$")[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no special status for "strip to the left", "strip to the right", etc.  The one general method is `re.sub` -- for example, to "strip everything up to the last slash included" ("to the left" as ksh conceptualizes it):

```
name = re.sub(r'(.*/)(.*)', r'\2', name)
```

and to strip "the last slash and everything following" ("to the right" per ksh):

```
name = re.sub(r'(.*)/.*', r'\1', name)
```

These match as much as possible because the `*` in RE patterns is greedy; use `*?` instead for non-greedy matching ("as little as possible") instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def strip_upto_max(astring, pattern):
    "${astring##*pattern}"
    return astring.rpartition(pattern)[2]
>>> def strip_from_max(astring, pattern):
    "${astring%%pattern*}"
    return astring.partition(pattern)[0]
>>> def strip_upto(astring, pattern):
    "${astring#*pattern}"
    return astring.partition(pattern)[2]
>>> def strip_from(astring, pattern):
    "${astring%pattern*}"
    return astring.rpartition(pattern)[0]

>>> strip_from("hello there", " t")
'hello'
>>> strip_upto("hello there", " t")
'here'

>>> text= "left/middle/right"
>>> strip_from(text, "/")
'left/middle'
>>> strip_upto(text, "/")
'middle/right'
>>> strip_upto_max(text, "/")
'right'
>>> strip_from_max(text, "/")
'left'
```

But if your intention is to use it with paths, check whether the [`os.path.dirname`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) (`${name%/*}`) and [`os.path.basename`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) (`${name##*/}`) functions have the functionality you require.